# По привычке - вводное?

Tags: пунктуация

Может ли " по привычке" быть вводным и нужна ли запятая в этом предложении?

Азербайджанская сторона не только продолжает провокации и артиллерийский обстрел мирных населенных пунктов Нагорного Карабаха, **но и, по привычке,** пытается перевернуть все с ног на голову, обвиняя карабахскую сторону в нанесении ударов по азербайджанским населенным пунктам.

Comment: Ошибок не видите?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Может ли " по привычке" быть вводным?

**Может.**

Из *"Словаря лингвистических терминов" Т.В. Жеребило:*

> [**вводные компоненты**](http://lingvistics_dictionary.academic.ru/460/%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B)
>
> <…>
>
> Говорящий оценивает содержание высказывания с разных позиций, чему
>   соответствуют грамматические значения вводных компонентов, выражающих:
>
> <...>
>
> г) степень обычности, нормальности сообщаемого: **В.к.** – *по обыкновению,*
>   *как обычно, **по привычке**, как водится, как правило, как всегда, как*
>   *иногда бывает, случается* и т.п.

То же и у  [**Леканта:**](https://books.google.ru/books?id=ld1fAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E,%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE,%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B5,%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%22&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E,%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE,%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B5,%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCs6O097HMAhXrC5oKHdvuC7kQ6AEIGzAA)

> Оценку обычности высказывания выражают следующие вводные конструкции:
>   *по обыкновению, как обычно, **по привычке…***

Примеры **из Нацкорпуса:**

> *Мы все трое в испуге подскочили, понимая, **по привычке,** что надо куда-то идти.* [Анатолий Приставкин. Кукушата или жалобная песнь для
>   успокоения сердца (1992)]
>
> *Ляля, **по привычке,** закрыла лицо ладонями, но никто не хотел щадить...* [Аркадий Львов. Двор (1981)]
>
> *А когда я, **по привычке,** попробовал опять подумать о чём-нибудь человеческом, то у меня, к моему удивлению, на этот раз ничего не
>   получилось.* [Валерий Медведев. Баранкин, будь человеком! (1957)]
>
> *Это были воронки, на которые он, **по привычке,** сначала не обратил внимания.* [В. П. Катаев. Сын полка (1944)]
>
> *Они сели, **по привычке,** на свои места, как сидели обычно в классе: Сеня Пичугин и Шура Капустина впереди, а Костя Рожков сзади всех, на
>   последней парте.* [Л. А. Кассиль. У классной доски (1942)]

.

Ну а выделять ли запятыми ***по привычке*** в приведённом в вопросе предложении? Однозначно на этот вопрос, думаю, нельзя ответить.  Читаете без пауз — не выделяйте; читаете с паузами — выделите.

В таких случаях решение о постановке знаков препинания принимает **автор текста.**

Comment: *Однозначно на этот вопрос, думаю, нельзя ответить.* - прокомментировал в тексте ответа.

Answer (score 3):

1) Обстоятельственная падежная форма **"по привычке"** (как другие нераспространенные обстоятельства)  **обособляется очень редко**, так как обычно вписывается в структуру предложения, **но исключения бывают**. В этом случае обособленное обстоятельство имеет значение добавочного сообщения, например:

А когда я, **по привычке**, попробовал опять подумать о чём-нибудь человеческом, то у меня, к моему удивлению, на этот раз ничего не получилось. Мы уже закончили! ― недовольно, **по привычке**, ответил начмед.Первое время я покупал ватрушки на двоих и грел полный чайник, **по привычке**. Рассказывали друг другу много анекдотов и уже не на кухне, но некоторые полушепотом, **по привычке**.

2) Может быть,  "по привычке" не часто называют вводным словом, хотя по значению оно напоминает тематику вводных слов, называемую **степенью обычности**  (как обычно, как всегда).

3) **В заданном предложении семантика "по привычке" не совсем обычная,** скорее здесь имелось в виду "по своему обыкновению". А вот это обстоятельство обособляется уже чаще, например: Воланд, **по своему обыкновению**, находился в спальне, а где был кот ― неизвестно (М. А. Булгаков).

4) Подводя итог можно сказать, что в нашем случае **обособление факультативное,** но оно имеет определенный смысл: обособленное обстоятельство выделяется, подчеркивается. Можно также сказать, что обособленный оборот является **средством художественной выразительности**, так как выражает ироническое отношение автора к описываемой ситуации.

Comment: Вас тоже прошу прочитать мой ответ, почему здесь однозначно не вводное.

Comment: "По привычке" в данном случае, действительно, важное слово, но  обособление членов предложения делается с одной из двух целей: (1) обозначение дополнительного характера сведений и (2) актуализация   (выделение, акцентирование). Здесь скорее имеет место именно  актуализация. Что касается отнесения  "по привычке" к  вводным словам, то мне этот вопрос не кажется принципиальным. Даже если назвать его вводным словом, это не значит отнести его к словам второстепенным, малозначащим. Наверное, вводные слова также могут играть важную роль. Тем не менее функция вводности здесь не на первом месте.

Comment: *Что касается отнесения "по привычке" к вводным словам, то мне этот вопрос не кажется принципиальным* - ничего себе! Важность же подразумевается не только стилистическая или семантическая даже, а еще и грамматическая. А по грамматике слово, важное для структуры предложения, изъятию без потери смысла не подлежащее. А вводное - как раз то, которое не нарушит грамматику настолько, что смысл изменится. Здесь - никак. Ну обстреляли разок, ну и что?  А тут вся соль в этом "по привычке", за которым читается недвусмысленное "наших бьют".

Comment: Кстати, это постоянный прием прокремлевской  журналистики. Та же Украина и Крым. Не просто обстреляли, а *опять* обстреляли. У потребителя складывается впечатление, что факт преступности одной из противоборствующих очевиден, доказан и признан самой "виновной" стороной.  А теперь уберите слово "опять". Эффект не тот. Поэтому же и в нашем случае "по привычке" - член предложения. Хотя мне нравится уже то, что вы все-таки допускаете неоднозначность "расклада". Не в пример некоторым.

Answer (score 2):

Это не вводное слово, обстоятельство. Как? - по привычке.

Comment: Так это не ваш коммент? А неизвестного модератора? Ну-ну.

Comment: behemothus, когда вас переполняет желание мне досадить, вы начинаете заметно хуже соображать. Спокойно, спокойно. Это насчет невменяемости.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39034/discussion-between-behemothus-and-niemand).

Answer (score 1):

Здесь - нет, точно не вводное, обособления не нужно. 
Может ли вообще быть вводным, не знаю. Наверное можно как-то исхитриться, но это не будут полностью естестественная речь.

Answer (score 1):

Я полностью согласен, что тут не вводное. Запятые не нужны.

Переношу "дискуссию" из комментариев.
Первый вопрос был, вводное ли слово "по привычке". 
 Фокус в том, что исчерпывающего списка вводных слов не существует. Есть слова, которые могут использоваться как вводные, есть такие, которые могут стать вводными окказионально.

*Niemand не ответил на этот вопрос.
Второй, нужна ли запятая, вообще проигнорировал.*

> Однозначно на этот вопрос, думаю, нельзя ответить.

Все-таки вполне можно по контексту. В нашей фразе "по привычке" - часть предложения без которого смысл изменится. Здесь автор в риторическом пылу доказывает именно постоянство нарушений только одной стороной (чем, кстати, выдает себя с головой как заказного писаку). Без этого и пафоса не будет. Поэтому здесь смысл "по привычке" - постоянно. А это значение уже никак не вводное.

> скорее здесь имелось в виду "по своему обыкновению".

Здесь скорее именно *постоянно*. А если даже и "по обыкновению", то все равно - как член предложения, без которого ни авторская оценка события, ни "черный пиар" оппонента не будут иметь смысла.

Comment: >> *Niemand не ответил на этот вопрос* С behemothus'ом совсем плохо - разучился читать. Второй случай за час, нехороший симптом. Первый с росписью, теперь вот тут. Там хоть слов было много... >> *Второй, нужна ли запятая, вообще проигнорировал* Ну, если на первый не ответил, чего уж на второй-то отвечать... Окказионально, что ли?

Comment: "окказионально" - wtf???

Comment: @Igor, здесь не принято изъясняться междометиями. Если Вас интересует значение слова, то словарь Вам в помощь. На первый раз: *ОККАЗИОНАЛЬНЫЙ, ая, ое; лен, льна (книжн.). Случайный, единичный.* (Ожегов)